# Expand column vector to left and right with certain offset to form 2D matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have some vectors with random length like,

```
a = [ 20
      78
      90
      180];

b = [ 54
      102
      1020];
```

How can I produce metric with like `n = 3` integers before and after each element like,

```
a1 = [17  18  19  20  21  22  23          b1 = [51   52   53   54   55   56   57
      75  76  77  78  79  80  81                99   100  101  102  103  104  105
      87  88  89  90  91  92  93                1017 1018 1019 1020 1021 1022 1023];
      177 178 179 180 181 182 183];
```

without any loops,
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfect setup for usage of [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with `@plus` handle -

```
n = 3;
a1 = bsxfun(@plus,a,-n:n)
b1 = bsxfun(@plus,b,-n:n)
```

Here, `-n:n` acts as the summation (because of `@plus`) offset array.